# What does "about" mean in this extract?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm a student studying English abroad. I couldn't understand something while reading an English article. I don't know why "about" was used in the emboldened sentence. Isn't "that's been the strangest thing" fine? I've thought "about" meant "concerning" or "nearly", but I think neither is right in this case. Therefore, please explain to me the meaning of that.

> Utah officials found a mysterious metal pillar in remote Red Rock
> Country in the southeastern part of the state while flying by
> helicopter on a routine search for sheep. Officials said they had no
> idea how the 10- to 12-foot-tall block of metal got there. "**That's
> been about the strangest thing that I've come across out there in all
> my years of flying**," helicopter pilot Bret Hutchings told KSL TV.

Besides, in the same sentence, isn't it better to use "is" rather than "has been"? I think using "is" looks more natural.

Comment: See: [about (adverb)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/about)

Comment: 'Nearly' is the sense here. Of all the strange things the pilot has seen during his career, this is almost the strangest. You're right, it is unusual to use _has been_ rather than _is_ or _was_  in this kind of sentence.

Comment: It would be better said adding 'just'; "just about"

Comment: Yes, this use of *about* means nearly, or approximately.

Comment: @ncmathsadist No; it's fine as it is, but like you I'd opt for the 'just about' version.  I suspect neither of us is from Utah.

Comment: Your first question has been thoroughly answered so I'll skip to the second. I'm an American, native English speaker learning Spanish. Someone (a native Spanish speaker) once reminded me that even native speakers don't speak their native language well sometimes. The use of "has been" does seem awkward to my ear but it's just an example of this phenomenon.

When you learn English well you may end up understanding the language better than some native speakers as they "learned" it but likely didn't "study" it as much as you have.

Comment: @Bishop2 What did your own research leave unclear, please?

Answer (score 17):

In this case, "about" is used in the sense of "approximately" or "nearly" (almost) and similar words, as mentioned in a comment. This is a valid meaning; the phrasing is somewhat colloquial/idiomatic, perhaps more common in some regions. As the question mentions, the sentence works perfectly well without the word, but becomes definite rather than *almost* definite.

Answer (score 8):

You said you know "about" to mean "concerning" or "nearly". Here, it means **"nearly"**:

> That's been nearly the strangest thing that I've come across out there
> in all my years of flying.

However, that's not all. The connotation to using "about the ..." is that it is informal, fitting in to a laid-back, friendly talk. Though your extract is from the BBC article [Metal monolith found by helicopter crew in Utah desert](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-55056570), it comes from a witness of the monolith and not a professional writer. The witness uses this expression to emphasise the sheer oddness of the monolith.

This is one of many such figures of speech exclusive to spoken language.

Comment: Who told you _about_ used in this sense is informal and "laid-back"? I have seen it used in this sense in the writings of many a good writer. And what is the _figure of speech_ here? @niamulbengali

Comment: The whole sentence sounds kind of "folksy".

Comment: "exclusive to spoken language" isn't really how I'd describe this usage of "about"

Answer (score 4):

This is actually the very first meaning [given in Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about):

## about

#### adverb

Definition of about (Entry 1 of 3)

1a : reasonably close to 
*about* a year ago

Answer (score 2):

Your second question, why use "has been" instead of "is", is also connected to the colloquialism. The speaker is reporting on the sequence of strange events he has experienced over his flying career, so the verb used implies a duration of time.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with other answers.  While they are close to the meaning of 'about', in context the speaker doesn't mean 'nearly' or 'almost'.  Better substitutes in the given passage would be 'likely' or 'quite possibly'.

The speaker is indicating that this is *the* strangest thing he can immediately remember.  It's possible that sometime, back in the past, he did see a stranger sight, but if so he cannot remember it now.  The 'about' (instead of simply saying "That's the strangest thing that I've come across ...") allows that wiggle room, just in case his colleague pipes up to remind him of that day they flew past the flying unicorn (for instance).